# How to pass parameters in routes.rb in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
get 'show_category', to: 'movies#show_category', as: 'show_category'
```

I have the above routes entry.

I use this code in my view:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr><td>

    <%= link_to category, show_category_url, :genre => category, :remote => true %> <%end%>

  </td></tr>
<% end %>
```

As shown above, I would like to pass a parameter named `genre` and pass the value of `category` into that parameter. But when I try to print the value of the parameter inside the target function in my controller, I don't get ay value there:

```
def show_category
  puts "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
  puts params[:genre]
end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass parameters in brackets

```
show_category_url(genre: category)
```